# Per-method operand stack V/S per-method local variables

Tags: java, jvm, stack

[JVM stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNI1D.png)
I'm not able to figure out what is the difference between Per-method operand stack & per-method local variables?
and how come the stack size is 65535 operands if JVM is a 32bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JVMs are 64-bit machines these days as even many phones are 64-bit.

The 64K operand is the number of local variables (though `long` and `double` take two) This only counts primitives and references. Objects are not on the stack at the bytecode level (though they can be with escape analysis at runtime)

Note: each method is limited to 64K so having more than 64K local variables is unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM has a distinction between values stored in variables and intermediate results of expressions: e.g. in `(a + b) + c`, a, b, and c are local variables, but the intermediate result of `a + b` is stored on the stack.

The maximum size of the stack has nothing in particular to do with the number of bits in a machine word.